# Permission to see certain pages

Tags: php, frames

I am creating a website where there are two user intefaces.  ONe for sellers and one for buyers.  Currently, I am storing these files under a folder (e.g: /interfaces/frame.php) So for both cases the files are stored there.

I am able to authenticate the user by checking the database for user type and making sure if its a buyer they only get to see buyer interface and if seller then seller interface.  The problem is that these files can publicly be accessed, so if you go to domain.com/interfaces/frame.php it will show it to you.

What changes can i make so that they are not publicly accessible but yet i can serve them to the user.

I am using include("file.php"); for loading the respective user interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its most basic you can add a check in each on of your files to make sure its called via an include,

main.php

> $isIncluded = 1;
>   ...rest of your page logic...
>   include("./includefile.php");

then in includefile.php

> if(!$isInclude){ die("Sorry, this page can not be accessed
>   directly."); }

Comment: so this is how i should do it:  $included=1;include("file.php");

Comment: Yup, then check in file.php that include = 1 but I should say something like an MVC layout would be better..

Answer (score 5):

You can store those files under the web root so if your directory is like this:

```
includes
  -permission-needed-files
public_html
  -CSS
  -Javascript
  -Images
  -Anything that can be accessed publicly
```

you can still include files from the includes folder, and since they are underneath the web root, they cannot be accessed publicly.

Another approach is to include a php file at the top of all permission-required files that checks the session variable to see if they are allowed to access that file.  If they are not use a header to redirect them

Answer (score 3):

Basically PHP is NOT bound to the Webroot with most Webservers.

So if you have a good hosting service you should be able to store PHP Files in a folder that is NOT accesible from the web at all. You then should store a php file that is just displaying things in the web folder and another one calling the database or containing data in the non web folder of your server.

The Web one can call the none web one via file system paths (not Web URLs).

(That would be a very, very lightweight implementation of the MVC Pattern Jonathan mentioned in his awnser).

When you're ready for using frameworks I would recommend Zend Framework.

Comment: Zend is very bloated. I personally recommend CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider looking into the Model View Controller development pattern, and perform access-logic in the controller when the pages themselves are requested. I would suggest both CodeIgniter and Kohana as two great frameworks to develop on. They are both very simple, and would help you address this problem in minutes.

Of course you would also need to make some provisions to your database to accomodate groups and roles. That way you would add users to groups, and then grant certain groups access to certain pages.

Comment: yup understood the point but how to handle the problem at the momemnt..?

Comment: @AAA You should handle it with a Controller. Within your controller check to see if the user is permitted to view the requested page. If so, load the View. If not, load a different view.